# Python server: How can I continously queue tasks while making sure only one at a time is processed

Tags: python, multithreading, object, queue

I have two tasks of which one is called every two seconds and the other one is called at random times. Both need to access an object that can't be called before the previous call is finished (if that happens I need to reboot the hardware device manually).

The object is from a class which allows the communication with a hardware device via sockets.

To do so I created a thread class, in order to run everything in the background and no other tasks are blocked. Within this class I implemented a queue: Two different functions put Tasks into the queue and a worker is supposed to execute the tasks !!NOT!! simultaneously.

As this entire project is a server it should run continuously.

Well here is my code and it obviously is not working. I would be very happy if anyone has a clue on how to solve this.

Update: 26.10.2020
In order to make my issue more clear I updated the code based on the answer from Artiom Kozyrev.

```
import time
from threading import Lock, Thread
import threading
from queue import Queue


class ThreadWorker(Thread):
    def __init__(self, _lock: Lock, _queue: Queue, name: str):
        # daemon=False means that process waits until all threads are finished
        # (not only main one and garbage collector)
        super().__init__(name=name, daemon=False)
        # lock prevents several worker threads do work simultaneously
        self.lock = _lock
        # tasks are send from the main thread via Queue
        self.queue = _queue

    def do_work(self, job):
        # lock context manager prevents other worker threads from working in the same time
        with self.lock:
            time.sleep(3)
            print(f"{threading.current_thread().getName()}: {job * 10}")

    def run(self):
        while True:
            job = self.queue.get()
            # "poison pillow" - stop message from queue
            if not job:
                break
            self.do_work(job)

def TimeStamp(msg):
    tElapsed = (time.time() - tStart)  # Display Thread Info
    sElap = int(tElapsed)
    msElap = int((tElapsed - sElap) * 1000)
    usElap = int((tElapsed - sElap - msElap / 1000) * 1000000)
    print(msg , ': ',  sElap, 's', msElap, 'ms', usElap, 'us')

def f1():
    TimeStamp("f1 start")
    time.sleep(2)
    TimeStamp("f1 finished")

def f2():
    TimeStamp("f2 start")
    time.sleep(6)
    TimeStamp("f2 finished")

def insertf1():
    for i in range(10):
        q.put(f1())
        time.sleep(2)

def insertf2():
    for i in range(10):
        time.sleep(10)
        q.put(f2())



q = Queue()
lock = Lock()
workers = [ThreadWorker(lock, q, f"Th-worker-{i}") for i in range(5)]  # create workers
for w in workers:
    w.start()

tStart = time.time()
threading.Thread(target=insertf1, daemon=True).start()
threading.Thread(target=insertf2, daemon=True).start()
```

The output is:

f1 start :  0 s 0 ms 0 us

f1 finished :  2 s 2 ms 515 us

f1 start :  4 s 9 ms 335 us

f1 finished :  6 s 9 ms 932 us

f1 start :  8 s 17 ms 428 us

f2 start :  10 s 12 ms 794 us

f1 finished :  10 s 28 ms 633 us

f1 start :  12 s 29 ms 182 us

f1 finished :  14 s 34 ms 411 us

f2 finished :  16 s 19 ms 330 us

f1 started before f2 was finished, which is what needs to be avoided.

Comment: If you have only a single thread consuming from the queue, I don't understand why you worry about 2 jobs running simultaneously?

Comment: One job is an existing background thread, where a new thread is created once a socket connection is established: CallFromExtern().  The other job should run in the background aswell not to disturb the user experience. Both jobs need access to a similar object but different functions. If a user executes this request and the server is currently using that object the hardware device will crash and needs to be manually rebooted. Therefore I need a queue so this object is thread save and never called before the objects function is finished.

Comment: Your `ControlQueue` class  inherits from both `threading.Thread` and `queue.Queue`, and at the same time it has instances of those two classes inside. Such a program structure is possible, but since you never seem to use the inherited `queue.Queue` functionality at all, I would recommend to review the design decisions, first of all determine how many threads and queues are needed, and what their role is.

Comment: You are not putting `f1` and `f2` in the queue.  You are putting the *results* of calling those functions in the queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do so you need to combine `Queue` and `Lock`. Lock will prevent worker-threads from working in the same time. Find code example below:

```py
import time
from threading import Lock, Thread
import threading
from queue import Queue


class ThreadWorker(Thread):
    def __init__(self, _lock: Lock, _queue: Queue, name: str):
        # daemon=False means that process waits until all threads are finished 
        # (not only main one and garbage collector)
        super().__init__(name=name, daemon=False) 
        # lock prevents several worker threads do work simultaneously
        self.lock = _lock
        # tasks are send from the main thread via Queue
        self.queue = _queue

    def do_work(self, job):
        # lock context manager prevents other worker threads from working in the same time
        with self.lock:
            time.sleep(3)
            print(f"{threading.current_thread().getName()}: {job * 10}")

    def run(self):
        while True:
            job = self.queue.get()
            # "poison pillow" - stop message from queue
            if not job:
                break
            self.do_work(job)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    q = Queue()
    lock = Lock()
    workers = [ThreadWorker(lock, q, f"Th-worker-{i}") for i in range(5)]  # create workers
    for w in workers:
        w.start()
    # produce tasks
    for i in range(10):
        q.put(i)
    # stop tasks with "poison pillow"
    for i in range(len(workers)):
        q.put(None)
```

**Edit based on additions to the question (Lock added)**

The main idea is that you should not run f1 and f2 without Lock.

```
import time
from threading import Lock, Thread
import threading
from queue import Queue


class ThreadWorker(Thread):
    def __init__(self, _lock: Lock, _queue: Queue, name: str):
        # daemon=False means that process waits until all threads are finished
        # (not only main one and garbage collector)
        super().__init__(name=name, daemon=False)
        # lock prevents several worker threads do work simultaneously
        self.lock = _lock
        # tasks are send from the main thread via Queue
        self.queue = _queue

    def do_work(self, f):
        # lock context manager prevents other worker threads from working in the same time
        with self.lock:
            time.sleep(3)
            print(f"{threading.current_thread().getName()}: {f()}")

    def run(self):
        while True:
            job = self.queue.get()
            # "poison pillow" - stop message from queue
            if not job:
                break
            self.do_work(job)


def TimeStamp(msg):
    tElapsed = (time.time() - tStart)  # Display Thread Info
    sElap = int(tElapsed)
    msElap = int((tElapsed - sElap) * 1000)
    usElap = int((tElapsed - sElap - msElap / 1000) * 1000000)
    print(msg, ': ',  sElap, 's', msElap, 'ms', usElap, 'us')


def f1():
    TimeStamp("f1 start")
    time.sleep(1)
    TimeStamp("f1 finished")
    return f"Func-1-{threading.current_thread().getName()}"


def f2():
    TimeStamp("f2 start")
    time.sleep(3)
    TimeStamp("f2 finished")
    return f"Func-2-{threading.current_thread().getName()}"


def insertf1():
    for i in range(5):
        q.put(f1)  # do not run f1 here! Run it in worker thread with Lock


def insertf2():
    for i in range(5):
        q.put(f2) # do not run f2 here! Run it in worker thread with Lock


q = Queue()
lock = Lock()
workers = [ThreadWorker(lock, q, f"Th-worker-{i}") for i in range(5)]  # create workers
for w in workers:
    w.start()

tStart = time.time()
threading.Thread(target=insertf1, daemon=True).start()
threading.Thread(target=insertf2, daemon=True).start()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it creates the issue as I had before.
To test it I created two threads:
threading.Thread(target=insertf1, daemon=True).start()
threading.Thread(target=insertf2, daemon=True).start(). Both threads insert functions f1 (every 2 seconds) and f2 (every 10 seconds) into the queue. f1 takes 2 seconds to execute and f2 takes 6 seconds to execute.

Comment: Now I printed the start and stop time for each task:
f1 start :  4 s 9 ms 335 us
f1 finished :  6 s 9 ms 932 us
f1 start :  8 s 17 ms 428 us
f2 start :  10 s 12 ms 794 us
f1 finished :  10 s 28 ms 633 us
f1 start :  12 s 29 ms 182 us
f1 finished :  14 s 34 ms 411 us
f2 finished :  16 s 19 ms 330 us

As you can see f1 is started before f2 is finished.

Comment: @BastHut can you add to the question what you changed in code to add Lock for the functions? And actually threads in my example are not ```daemon=True```, otherwise they will be finished when the main thread completes its work

Comment: I updated the main question based on your code, including the output

Comment: @BastHut I added information to my initial answer, I checked your code and see that f1 and f2 were not run with Lock. I changed insert1 and insert2 logic, now they do not give to Queue ready result, but send function to worker where the function is called. Note You have another choice, you can change  your code in other way and use Lock inside f1 and f2 then you'll send ready results to workers instead  of function itself.